# App installation in BigCommerce

Tags: api, oauth, bigcommerce

I have a problem with BigCommerce installation process.
According to documentation (https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/callback) I receive GET request, do exchange for  OAuth info via POST request and return HTML page to user.

App seems successfully installed, I can see it in left panel, but it don't send request to LoadCallback with signed payload. When I click to application's icon it just hides/shows HTML page that I send during intallation.

Seems like the only way to make BigCommerce do LoadCallback request is to open app after relogin.

Did I do something wrong during installation process?

Comment: Did you find a way around this?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is intended behavior. Most apps have a sign up process that cause a frame reload of the app. You can force a reload after installation or use a form submission action via javascript. Alternatively, you can reload the control panel and reopen app or relogin and open.

Comment: Yes, I can make redirec from page that I sent to BigCommerce but then the page where I redirect user will not receive LoadCallback as well and I can not login user without signed payload.
Relogin works, but it seems not user-friendly.
Can I force control panle to reload and reopen app?

Comment: The oauth in our case is the sign up process so we need the user to manually refresh the browser as well. You cannot force a reload of the parent page due to cross domain issues. It looks like you need a special page that tells the user to refresh which, as pas_art says, is terrible UX.

Comment: @GuyLowe do you not have any sort of form submission? how is the data getting confirmed/form completion being denoted?

Comment: We have an MVVM site so there is no need for form submission. However, I am now forcing the user to refresh their browser to re-auth them. Thanks for the help, this looks like the best solution for now.